# hdfs file streaming using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs

I am not able to get my Spark job to stream "old" files from HDFS. If my Spark job is down for some reason (e.g. demo, deployment) but the writing/moving to HDFS directory is continuous.

Can we process all files from the last processed file?

what should I do?

I am using this in java:

```
JavaDStream<String> dStream = streamingContext.textFileStream(filePath).cache();
```

Comment: are you really want to use DStreams? Structured streaming should work better in that case (imho): https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources